# How to initialize a sort and filter repeated element in protocol buffer?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a message like

```
message Email {
    string id = 1;
    uint32 reply = 2;
}
message ListEmail {
    repeated Email email = 1;
}
```

in a function in C++, I want to sort and paginate this , something like

```
void sortbyreply (size_t skip, size_t limit, ListEmail* listemail)
```

I can iterate over the list and copy to a new one , but is there a smarter way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort the listemail you can use std::sort

```
std::sort(
  listemail->mutable_email()->begin(),
  listemail->mutable_email()->end(),
  [](const Email& a, const Email& b) {
      return a.reply() > b.reply();
  });
```

There is a DeleteSubrange in protobuf3 that can prune repeated fields, dont know if it is efficient though

```
listemail->mutable_email()->DeleteSubrange(0,skip);
listemail->mutable_email()->DeleteSubrange(limit,listemail->email_size()-limit);
```

Comment: A more efficient variation on this is to use `pointer_begin()` and `pointer_end()` instead of `begin()` and `end()`. This way you're just copying pointers instead of copying around the actual protobuf objects.